# tomcat not able to start in jpda start mode

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, java

This is my **catalina.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java"
CATALINA_PID="/usr/local/tomcat/tomcat.pid"
CATALINA_HOME="/usr/local/tomcat"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xloggc:/usr/local/tomcat/logs/gc.log -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0 -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=10 -XX:CMSIncrementalSafetyFactor=75 -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1536m -XX:PermSize=48m -XX:MaxPermSize=174m"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=ISO-8859-1"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1"
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8097 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=30"
# OS specific support.  $var _must_ be set to either true or false.
cygwin=false
darwin=false
os400=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
Darwin*) darwin=true;;
OS400*) os400=true;;
esac

# resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
PRG="$0"

while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
  fi
done

# Get standard environment variables
PRGDIR=`dirname "$PRG"`

# Only set CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." >/dev/null; pwd`

# Copy CATALINA_BASE from CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE="$CATALINA_HOME"

# Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
# but allow them to be specified in setenv.sh, in rare case when it is needed.
CLASSPATH=

if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
fi

# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched
if $cygwin; then
  [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] && JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$JRE_HOME" ] && JRE_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JRE_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$CATALINA_HOME"`
  [ -n "$CATALINA_BASE" ] && CATALINA_BASE=`cygpath --unix "$CATALINA_BASE"`
  [ -n "$CLASSPATH" ] && CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --unix "$CLASSPATH"`
fi

# For OS400
if $os400; then
  # Set job priority to standard for interactive (interactive - 6) by using
  # the interactive priority - 6, the helper threads that respond to requests
  # will be running at the same priority as interactive jobs.
  COMMAND='chgjob job('$JOBNAME') runpty(6)'
  system $COMMAND

  # Enable multi threading
  export QIBM_MULTI_THREADED=Y
fi

# Get standard Java environment variables
if $os400; then
  # -r will Only work on the os400 if the files are:
  # 1. owned by the user
  # 2. owned by the PRIMARY group of the user
  # this will not work if the user belongs in secondary groups
  . "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh
else
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh ]; then
    . "$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/setclasspath.sh
  else
    echo "Cannot find $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setclasspath.sh"
    echo "This file is needed to run this program"
    exit 1
  fi
fi

# Add on extra jar files to CLASSPATH
if [ ! -z "$CLASSPATH" ] ; then
  CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH":
fi
CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH""$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/bootstrap.jar

if [ -z "$CATALINA_OUT" ] ; then
  CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
fi

if [ -z "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" ] ; then
  # Define the java.io.tmpdir to use for Catalina
  CATALINA_TMPDIR="$CATALINA_BASE"/temp
fi

# Add tomcat-juli.jar to classpath
# tomcat-juli.jar can be over-ridden per instance
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/tomcat-juli.jar" ] ; then
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_BASE/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
else
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CATALINA_HOME/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
fi

# Bugzilla 37848: When no TTY is available, don't output to console
have_tty=0
if [ "`tty`" != "not a tty" ]; then
    have_tty=1
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin; then
  JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
  JRE_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$JRE_HOME"`
  CATALINA_HOME=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_HOME"`
  CATALINA_BASE=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_BASE"`
  CATALINA_TMPDIR=`cygpath --absolute --windows "$CATALINA_TMPDIR"`
  CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$CLASSPATH"`
  JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS=`cygpath --path --windows "$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS"`
fi

# Set juli LogManager config file if it is present and an override has not been issued
if [ -z "$LOGGING_CONFIG" ]; then
  if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/logging.properties ]; then
    LOGGING_CONFIG="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties"
  else
    # Bugzilla 45585
    LOGGING_CONFIG="-Dnop"
  fi
fi

if [ -z "$LOGGING_MANAGER" ]; then
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
else
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $LOGGING_MANAGER"
fi

# Uncomment the following line to make the umask available when using the
# org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=`umask`"

# ----- Execute The Requested Command -----------------------------------------

# Bugzilla 37848: only output this if we have a TTY
if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Using CATALINA_BASE:   $CATALINA_BASE"
  echo "Using CATALINA_HOME:   $CATALINA_HOME"
  echo "Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: $CATALINA_TMPDIR"
  if [ "$1" = "debug" ] ; then
    echo "Using JAVA_HOME:       $JAVA_HOME"
  else
    echo "Using JRE_HOME:        $JRE_HOME"
  fi
  echo "Using CLASSPATH:       $CLASSPATH"
  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo "Using CATALINA_PID:    $CATALINA_PID"
  fi
fi

if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
  if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
    JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
    JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
  fi
  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS"
  shift
fi

if [ "$1" = "debug" ] ; then
  if $os400; then
    echo "Debug command not available on OS400"
    exit 1
  else
    shift
    if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
      if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Using Security Manager"
      fi
      shift
      exec "$_RUNJDB" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
        -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
        -sourcepath "$CATALINA_HOME"/../../java \
        -Djava.security.manager \
        -Djava.security.policy=="$CATALINA_BASE"/conf/catalina.policy \
        -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
        -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
    else
      exec "$_RUNJDB" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
        -Djava.endorsed.dirs="$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" \
        -sourcepath "$CATALINA_HOME"/../../java \
        -Dcatalina.base="$CATALINA_BASE" \
        -Dcatalina.home="$CATALINA_HOME" \
        -Djava.io.tmpdir="$CATALINA_TMPDIR" \
        org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
    fi
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "run" ]; then

  shift
  if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
    if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Using Security Manager"
    fi
    shift
    eval exec \"$_RUNJAVA\" \"$LOGGING_CONFIG\" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\" -classpath \"$CLASSPATH\" \
      -Djava.security.manager \
      -Djava.security.policy==\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\" \
      -Dcatalina.base=\"$CATALINA_BASE\" \
      -Dcatalina.home=\"$CATALINA_HOME\" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
  else
    eval exec \"$_RUNJAVA\" \"$LOGGING_CONFIG\" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\" -classpath \"$CLASSPATH\" \
      -Dcatalina.base=\"$CATALINA_BASE\" \
      -Dcatalina.home=\"$CATALINA_HOME\" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "start" ] ; then

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      if [ -s "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        echo "Existing PID file found during start."
        if [ -r "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
          PID=`cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
          ps -p $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
          if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
            echo "Tomcat appears to still be running with PID $PID. Start aborted."
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Removing/clearing stale PID file."
            rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
            if [ $? != 0 ]; then
              if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
              else
                echo "Unable to remove or clear stale PID file. Start aborted."
                exit 1
              fi
            fi
          fi
        else
          echo "Unable to read PID file. Start aborted."
          exit 1
        fi
      else
        rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
          if [ ! -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
            echo "Unable to remove or write to empty PID file. Start aborted."
            exit 1
          fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi

  shift
  touch "$CATALINA_OUT"
  if [ "$1" = "-security" ] ; then
    if [ $have_tty -eq 1 ]; then
      echo "Using Security Manager"
    fi
    shift
    eval \"$_RUNJAVA\" \"$LOGGING_CONFIG\" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\" -classpath \"$CLASSPATH\" \
      -Djava.security.manager \
      -Djava.security.policy==\"$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.policy\" \
      -Dcatalina.base=\"$CATALINA_BASE\" \
      -Dcatalina.home=\"$CATALINA_HOME\" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"

  else
    eval \"$_RUNJAVA\" \"$LOGGING_CONFIG\" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\" -classpath \"$CLASSPATH\" \
      -Dcatalina.base=\"$CATALINA_BASE\" \
      -Dcatalina.home=\"$CATALINA_HOME\" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start \
      >> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"

  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo $! > "$CATALINA_PID"
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "stop" ] ; then

  shift

  SLEEP=5
  if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
    echo $1 | grep "[^0-9]" >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
      SLEEP=$1
      shift
    fi
  fi

  FORCE=0
  if [ "$1" = "-force" ]; then
    shift
    FORCE=1
  fi

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      if [ -s "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
          echo "PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted."
          exit 1
        fi
      else
        echo "PID file is empty and has been ignored."
      fi
    else
      echo "\$CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist. Is Tomcat running? Stop aborted."
      exit 1
    fi
  fi

  eval \"$_RUNJAVA\" $JAVA_OPTS \
    -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\" -classpath \"$CLASSPATH\" \
    -Dcatalina.base=\"$CATALINA_BASE\" \
    -Dcatalina.home=\"$CATALINA_HOME\" \
    -Djava.io.tmpdir=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\" \
    org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" stop

  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      while [ $SLEEP -ge 0 ]; do
        kill -0 `cat "$CATALINA_PID"` >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
          rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
          if [ $? != 0 ]; then
            if [ -w "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
              cat /dev/null > "$CATALINA_PID"
            else
              echo "Tomcat stopped but the PID file could not be removed or cleared."
            fi
          fi
          break
        fi
        if [ $SLEEP -gt 0 ]; then
          sleep 1
        fi
        if [ $SLEEP -eq 0 ]; then
          if [ $FORCE -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Tomcat did not stop in time. PID file was not removed."
          fi
        fi
        SLEEP=`expr $SLEEP - 1 `
      done
    fi
  fi

  if [ $FORCE -eq 1 ]; then
    if [ -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
      echo "Kill failed: \$CATALINA_PID not set"
    else
      if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        PID=`cat "$CATALINA_PID"`
        echo "Killing Tomcat with the PID: $PID"
        kill -9 $PID
        rm -f "$CATALINA_PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
          echo "Tomcat was killed but the PID file could not be removed."
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi

elif [ "$1" = "configtest" ] ; then

    eval \"$_RUNJAVA\" $JAVA_OPTS \
      -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS\" -classpath \"$CLASSPATH\" \
      -Dcatalina.base=\"$CATALINA_BASE\" \
      -Dcatalina.home=\"$CATALINA_HOME\" \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\" \
      org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap configtest
    result=$?
    if [ $result -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Configuration error detected!"
    fi
    exit $result

elif [ "$1" = "version" ] ; then

    "$_RUNJAVA"   \
      -classpath "$CATALINA_HOME/lib/catalina.jar" \
      org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo

else

  echo "Usage: catalina.sh ( commands ... )"
  echo "commands:"
  if $os400; then
    echo "  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger (not available on OS400)"
    echo "  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager (not available on OS400)"
  else
    echo "  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger"
    echo "  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager"
  fi
  echo "  jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger"
  echo "  run               Start Catalina in the current window"
  echo "  run -security     Start in the current window with security manager"
  echo "  start             Start Catalina in a separate window"
  echo "  start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager"
  echo "  stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end"
  echo "  stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end"
  echo "  stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
  echo "  stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
  echo "  configtest        Run a basic syntax check on server.xml - check exit code for result"
  echo "  version           What version of tomcat are you running?"
  echo "Note: Waiting for the process to end and use of the -force option require that \$CATALINA_PID is defined"
  exit 1

fi
```

after starting **./catalina.sh jpda start**
I am getting

```
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp
```

and i am not able to remote debug in eclipse

But if i start normal tomcat is starting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **either** set the `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp...` switches in the JAVA_OPTS environment variable, **or** pass the `jpda` arguments to `catalina.sh`, but not both. If you do both, it will try to load the agent twice and give you an error.

**Edit**: Personally I prefer to use the JAVA_OPTS switches because they give more control (e.g. to set the port number). Once you have done that and restarted Tomcat, you should be able to connect from Eclipse with the debugger.

To connect from Eclipse, you need to create a Debug Configuration of type "Remote Java Application": From the "Run" menu, select "Debug Configurations...". In the left pane, select "Remote Java Application" and click the "New" button. In the right pane, select the Project, and enter the IP address of your Tomcat server in the Host field. You can leave the default values for the other fields. Then click Debug at the bottom and the Eclipse debugger should connect to Tomcat.